# Connect redux to a single react component

Tags: reactjs, redux

Though it may not be a good pattern, I'm interested in how it's possible to connect a single react component to a store.

For instance if I had:

```
const store = createStore();

const testComponent = props => {
    const name = store.name; // this won't work because it won't update

    return (<p>{ name }</p>);
};
```

I'm guessing I need to pass in the values from the store via props somehow in order to get the component to update automatically. `connect`, however, seems to require that the store already by injected into the context via a provided.

I could relatively easily just create an additional component as a parent to this one, but I'm interested to know how this is possible.

Comment: why don't you look how the library author does this: https://egghead.io/lessons/react-redux-extracting-container-components-filterlink (starts at 5:00)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't wanna wrap your component in `connect`, you can use `useSelector` hook from redux, which works like this:

```
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'

const TestComponent = () => {
  const name = useSelector(state => state.name)
  return <p>{name}</p>
}
```

But you still need to inject the store via a provider.